# javascript error: Invalid argument in IE on anonymous function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting a weird error in internet explorer (I tried on IE 8)
Everything is fine with a different browser.

Invalid argument on a function similar to this one (I can't post the original one as it is from a non redistributable library which was originally obfuscated and compressed):

```
function createADiv() {
    var f = document.createElement('div');
    f.set = [function (z) { // error on this line
        f.style.width = z
    }, function (z) {
        f.style.height = z
    }];
    return f;
 }
```

The problem lies in the scope of f but I don't get why using f inside the anonymous functions shouldn't work.

Any ideas about how to circumvent this Internet Explorer bug?

I've checked other "invalid argument error" but this one seems to be a different case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you planing to use this f div?

Comment: var test = createADiv();
test.set[0]("10px");

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
function createADiv() {
    var f = document.createElement('div');
    f.set = {
        width: function (z) { // error on this line
            f.style.width = z
        }, 
        height: function (z) {
            f.style.height = z
        }
    };
    return f;
 }
```

now when you create a div you can do this:

```
var newDiv = createADiv();
newDiv.set.height("200px");
```

but to tell you the truth this is useless because javascript already does this:

```
newDiv.style.height = "200px";
```

there is not much difference

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but I'm trying to use a 20k js library which constantly use this code structure

Comment: @Jser in this case you can use the code above, it will won't have any issue with IE

Comment: It's not that simple, I can't change this code

I've several (+100) calls which set height and width using variables
(e.g: sample.set[i](k+"10px"))

I just want to understand why the hell I can't use f inside those anonymous functions in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, try re-writing it as this

```
function createADiv() {
    var f = document.createElement('div');
    f.set = [function a (z) { // error on this line
        f.style.width = z
    }, function b (z) {
        f.style.height = z
    }];
    return f;
 }
```